# Did Emperor Palpatine break the Rule of Two?

Tags: star-wars

Palpatine trained Darth Maul from a young age in the dark of the force and he was called Darth but Darth Plagueis was still alive while he was being trained and during episode 1 so there were 3 Sith, Plagueis, Maul and Palpatine?